# Create toolbar to close WebView on Swift

Tags: ios, swift

In my app, I have a button where on click, it loads another ViewController to display WebView on full screen. The problem here is how do I create a toolbar on top just like Facebook, where I can close the WebView.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In iOS 9, you can use `SFSafariViewController` which is a WebView controller (with the safari engine power) with all the needed controls (back button, close, etc). You have to `import SafariServices` in order to use it.

Otherwise, you can just add a toolbar in your storyboard over the webview and add buttons hooked to IBACtions that implement "back" and "close" functionality (both UIWebView and WKWebView provide easy access to their navigation methods and adding a close button for the view controller is pretty easy: `self.dismisViewController(animated:true)` if it is a modal, or `self.popViewController` if it is pushed on a navigation controller stack).

Comment: Watched the keynote. And a very simple implementation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you must embed your viewcontroller(ViewController to display WebView) in uinavigationcontroller, and set left navigation bar item is a close button and implement action (touchupinside) for it to close this viewcontroller
It is pop if you push viewcontroller or dismiss if you presentviewcontroller